# Is KillTimer really necessary?

Tags: winapi, timer

This may seem to be a duplicate question for [Is KillTimer necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177065/is-killtimer-necessary), but i would like to confirm this with **credible source**.

Does destroying window really free the resource allocated by the OS for the timer? (does `DestroyWindowsTimers` really get called let alone if such function actually exists? if so, where?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. From the documentation of [DestroyWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx) (with emphasis added):

> **The function sends `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_NCDESTROY` messages** to the window to deactivate it and remove the keyboard focus from it. The function also destroys the window's menu, flushes the thread message queue, **destroys timers**, removes clipboard ownership, and breaks the clipboard viewer chain (if the window is at the top of the viewer chain).

Answer (score 2):

Doing a google search the only actual real looking reference to it looked to be some Win2k source code.  The url ended with `/Censorship/win2k_sources/private/.../timers.c`, I'm assuming from the [source code leak](http://news.cnet.com/2100-7349_3-5158496.html) a while back.  I did not look at the code, nor will I post a link here.

That function most likely exist - something like that almost has to exist for timers linked to window handles - since the timer message is delivered to a specific window handle.

I can't see anywhere in the documentation that states that you don't have to call `KillTimer` to get rid of a timer.  So based on the documented contract, you need to call `KillTimer`.  In practice Windows will probably clean it up for you, but since that is undocumented behavior you should write your code to follow the documented behavior and call `KillTimer` on all your timers.